# Git rebasing to upstream

Tags: git

So I forked a project, and made a few changes and pushed those to origin/master. I didn't intend to send these changes back to upstream.  All was fine and good until now, but now I have some changes I do want to push upstream.

Can I rebase back to upstream in a different branch, and commit to that branch? Can I commit these changes from my branch?  Have I horribly mangled my repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, no mangling. Just branch from upstream/master, make your commits there, and then you can push (or pull-request) those commits, which fit neatly onto upstream/master.

If you have A---B---C, where upstream/master is at A and master is at C, meaning B and C are commits you don't want to send upstream, then:

```
git checkout -b to-send-upstream A
# work, work, work
# commits
git log A..HEAD # this will be the commits to send upstream
```

If you have commits you're not going to send back on master, it might be simpler to keep track of things if you move those into a different branch and keep your master in sync with upstream/master:

```
git branch my-stuff-not-sent-upstream
git reset --hard A # will wipe out local changes!
git push origin master -f # can lose history if a shared remote!
git push origin my-stuff-not-sent-upstream
```

will effectively replace "master" with "my-stuff-not-sent-upstream" and set master and origin/master back to the same commit as upstream/master.

Comment: branch off upstream/master you mean?  What's the command to do that, might be the missing piece for me.

Comment: Updated my answer after realizing that origin != upstream. Make more sense?

Comment: Awesome this is what I was looking for.  I was trying to rebase back, but it was causing much head ache and little results.

Comment: As a best practice, should I make these changes into a branch.  Do a pull to upstream, if it's accepted there merge to master?

Comment: I can't speak to "best practice", but I'd expect that after a successful pull request, and after you pull from upstream, you'll already see it merged.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming commits A,B,C are your private changes, and commits 1,2,3 are what you want to push up, your history will look like so:

```
                   (origin/master)
                  /
.... o - A - B - C - 1 - 2 - 3  (master)
      \
       (upstream/master)
```

Now you want to move 1,2,3 to a new branch from upstream:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b upstream
git rebase origin/master --onto upstream/master
```

What this does is switch to a new branch called `upstream` where your current `master` is. Then it rebases commits 1,2,3 after commit referenced by `upstream/master`.

After the operation you will have:

```
         1' - 2' - 3' (upstream)
        /
       /           (origin/master)
      /           /
.... o - A - B - C - 1 - 2 - 3  (master)
      \
       (upstream/master)
```

Now you will be ready to push upstream branch to the upstream remote.

Comment: is --onto a shortcut to using the commit hash?  This is fantastic, thanks a lot for describing the process.

Comment: --onto specifies that you want to pick up a branch with all its commits, clip it out of the commit graph, and reattach it *onto* the specified branch/commit.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to add upstream as a remote.

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/upstream/repo.git
```

Meaning you not only have "origin" (which references your own clone on the GitHub side), but also "upstream" (which is the original repo you have forked on the GitHub side).

Then you need to fetch upstream, and checkout from there:

```
git checkout -b upstream/master
```

You can make your commits there, and then push back to origin, allowing you to make a clean pull request from there.

Comment: I should already have the original repo on upstream, but when I run checkout -b upstream/master, I get `error: unable to resolve reference refs/heads/upstream/master: Not a directory`
`fatal: Failed to lock ref for update: Not a directory`

Comment: @Drew: that should work only if your '`git remote -v`does list 'upstream' as one of the remote repo you have associated with your local repo.