# How can I submit partial change of my forked repo as patch?

Tags: github

I forked a repo from GitHub and make a bunch of changes. Then I found one of my modification in one file can be a patch to an issue of the original repo, but the author don't want to merge my other modifications, so I don't want to send a pull request directly. And I think forking it again and just modify that file to make a patch and then send pull request seems not so elegant. Are there any "standard" way to do that?

Comment: This answer also seems to address your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850284/git-rebasing-to-upstream

Comment: Thanks！It's exactly what I am looking for. But I appreciate the selected answer more because I just want to ask how to group the commits. It's a more complete answer for me :-)

Comment: How do you create a pull request (or commit) that just contains just one, or few files from one commit? (Basically the same question, just finer detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, you should make a new branch with the same root, then use [cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) to add every commit you made except those who are not accepted by the author.

Then send a pull request on this branch.

Moreover, if you want to regroup all your modifications into one simple commit, you may use a [squash](http://ariejan.net/2011/07/05/git-squash-your-latests-commits-into-one/) rebase on a local branch before pushing it online.

Answer (score 1):

Write down the SHA-1 hash of the desired commit. Switch back to the original project's master branch, create a new branch off of it and [`cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) that one commit onto the new branch.

You can then push the new branch to GitHub and send a PR with its changes.

If you have modified multiple files within one commit, you'll have to rewrite the commit somehow.