# gitHub -- How do you make partial pull request or commit containing a few selected files?

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Using gitHub (and Eclipse Egit, and SourceTree) with a forked repo, how can I make a pull request that just contains a few select files I want pulled?
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188993/how-can-i-submit-partial-change-of-my-forked-repo-as-patch) asks almost the same thing, but addresses 'cherry-picking' a single or group of commits.  I seem to need to have a pull request with just a few files from within a larger commit.

I tend to make a lot of changes to a lot of files putting in debugging code then find a solution that may involve only a change to a file or two.  I don't commit very frequently so I don't have have a commit that contains only the changes that fix the problem (and I like keeping the debugging hooks in my copy of the code.)

I'd like SourceTree or eGit/Eclipse to: 1) show me which files are different between two commits and 2) let me select which files to include in a pull request.  Perhaps I could do some selective merge files in my current master head and the master of the upstream repo?

Comment: *"I seem to need to have a pull request with just a few files from within a larger commit."* GitHub pull requests (as well as native Git operations like `fetch`, `pull`, `push`, and `cherry-pick`) operate on commits, not files. The only way to make them include changes to only a few files is to split your single large commit into multiple smaller commits and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to check out a number of files from a given commit / tree / revision.

To do this use:

```
git checkout [tree-ish] -- [paths]
```

`[tree-ish]` is a git-ism that basically means a commit, tag or branch, or something that refers to one of those. So if you have a remote `remotes/foo/bar` and you want `baz.c` from that revision, you do:

```
git checkout remotes/foo/bar -- baz.c
```

A 'pull request' is not a git thing, but a github thing. You will need to do a `git remote add` to add the repo you want to pull, then use `git fetch` or `git remote update` to pull the relevant information, then use the appropriate branch name in the above to get the file(s) you want.

Comment: I think this is on the right track.  I was thrown off by 'checkout' because I thought that just changed your local copy to match some named commit/tree/branch/tag.  The -patch sounds like it leaves you in your currently checked out branch and _replaces/adds_ files you specify with those from commit you specify.  --  Presumably this creates a new commit, or I have to commit and push this newly modified tree.

Comment: I understand a lot more about git does and what is done in the remote server(gitHub) by looking at the [HTTP API to gitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request).  I see that a pull request contains 1) the name of the branch copy things from and 2) the name of the branch to copy to(ie update) (and some comment text)  -- And that branch, or 'tree-ish' is just effectively a 'pointer' to a specifc 'tree' of files (that is to be copied to matched)

Comment: I don't understand the 'fetch remote add'  Is this to create a named reference my local 'branch'/'commit', updated tree?

Comment: @Ribo I did not say `fetch remote add`. I said `git remote add` which adds the remote - i.e. the reference to the remote server, but doesn't actually pull any changesets from it, then either `git fetch` or `git remote update` to pull the changesets from the remote server into `remotes/foo/[branchnames]`