# doing clean git pull-request to upstream

Tags: git, pull-request

I've cloned a repo (made sure to mark the original repo as `upstream`) and went the gitflow way: create a `develop` branch from which all new features are created and commited back to. Every push to `Master` from `develop` is by definition a release, meaning `master` is always deployable. I like this setup a lot.

Now sometimes aside from this flow I may want to contribute back to `upstream` some feature that I keep in separate feature-branches. However since a feature-branch is created from `develop HEAD` and `develop` may have already had other feature-branches merged back into, this gives a problem:

- merging the specific `feature branch` back into my own `develop` is ok
- but I'm not sure how to do a clean pullrequest from this `feature branch`. I.e: without all the code-changes of `previous feature branches` that were merged into `develop` before I started the current `feature branch`. I hope this makes sense.

I'm pretty sure `rebasing` doesn't help, since this only updates my local feature branch with commits of `upstream` that happened in the meantime. It doesn't help to 'clean' the local feature branch with inherited code changes from `develop`.

So, how to do this?

Comment: So is your `feature-branch` remote? If so, you can do a `git pull origin feature-branch` if you're HEAD is on `feature-branch` and it will pull just fine.

Comment: This seems somewhat similar to this question... But not a duplicate. It maybe helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850284/git-rebasing-to-upstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do in this case is to create a new local *feature* branch from the HEAD of the branch you want to contribute to (which would be in the *upstream* repository). Then checkout this branch and `git cherry-pick` the commit range [1] that implements the feature you want to contribute (the commit range will come from your local *developer* branch).

After that, you can publish your new *feature* branch and you can submit a clean pull-request from it.

1. [How to cherry-pick multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670970/how-to-cherry-pick-multiple-commits)

Comment: going to have to read up on this, but on first glance this seems indeed the way to go. Thanks

Comment: If this was useful, can you accept the answer? If not, tell me I will try to clarify my answer. Cheers!