# How do I pull-request at the certain commits in GitHub

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Make an example here, I have a development branch committed like this:

**"Development" branch**
June 08 - commit 12
June 07 - commit 11
June 06 - commit 10
June 06 - commit 09
June 06 - commit 08
June 05 - commit 07
June 05 - commit 06
June 02 - commit 05
June 02 - commit 04
June 02 - commit 03
June 01 - commit 02
June 01 - commit 01

**"Master" branch**
-no commit right now-

I want commit 01 until commit 05 to be the `first pull request` into master branch.
Then, I want commit 06 until commit 10 to be `second pull request` into master branch.

How can do I do this in GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pull request on github always ask for one branch to be merged into another. you need to create another branch (that is a very lightweight operation) at commit 5, and request a pull for that branch. after that you can request a pull request for your development branch pointing to commit 10, or if development moved on in the meantime, you need to create another branch pointing to commit 10.

long story short: commits are not pulled individually, but branches are merged. for the former, read about "cherry-pick" and/or possibly "rebase", but those are not what github does.

Comment: I answered a very similar question, which basically recommends the same as this answer, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17605084/269753

Answer (score 0):

You can do a git fetch to fetch the whole repository first

Then you can make a merge to a particular commit for master branch.

1 step

```
master =====================>
                           /
Developement c1=c2=c3=c4=c5=c6=c7=c8=c9
```

2 step

```
master ==================================>
                           /            /
Developement c1=c2=c3=c4=c5=c6=c7=c8=c9
```